# Can I "force update" a SharePoint Add-in installed through the Office Store?

Tags: office-365, upgrade, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-store

Consider a Sharepoint Add-in hsoted on the Office Store. The add-in is installed by a customer to her Sharepoint 2013 on premise or to his Sharepoint Online hosted in Office 365.

Is it possible for me, the add-in publisher, to publish an updated version to the store so that it gets deployed to the customer's installation without their having to take any action?

If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Update-SPAppInstance -Identity $instance -App $spapp` ?

[MSDN Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219631.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this technique satisfies my requirement. This would require the add-in publisher to be able to run the PowerShell on every machine where the customers installed the add-in. This is simply not possible.